# Add label in center of imageView

Tags: swift

I have the two images like in the picture at the end of the question (the image of a list and a red dot). I want to add a label in the center of the red dot. This is my code that doesn't work:

```
image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pallino"))
image.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: self.view.frame.height-60, width: 22, height: 22)
self.view.addSubview(image)
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.width/2
label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.image.center.x, y: self.image.center.y, width: image.frame.size.width, height: image.frame.size.height))
label.text = "4"
label.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15.0)
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.textColor = UIColor.black
image.addSubview(label)
```

Can someone tell me were am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in this line:

```
label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.image.center.x, y: self.image.center.y, width: image.frame.size.width, height: image.frame.size.height))
```

*self.image.center.x* - [The center point is specified in points in the coordinate system of its superview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622627-center), it is mean that *self.image.center* is not center of *image*

You need frame for label, something like this:

```
let imageSize = 22
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
label.aligment = .center
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set constraint in your label(centered Horizontally and Vertically). Try with the following code.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "4"
label.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15.0)
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.textColor = UIColor.black
image.addSubview(label)
label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.image.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.image.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the label in `UIImageView` you can refer to this example which is tested and working solution.

```
extension UIImageView {

    /// Create label programmatically
    /// - Returns: UILabel
    private func ageSensitiveLabel() -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height))
        label.text = "Content"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 5.0)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }

    /// Add label as subview to UIImageView
    func addAgeSensitiveLabel() {
        self.subviews.forEach { view in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        self.addSubview(ageSensitiveLabel())
    }
}
```

**Use it with UIImageView**

```
imageView.addAgeSensitiveLabel()
```